# How do I do MongoDB console-style queries in PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm trying to get a MongoDB query from the javascript console into my PHP app.  What I'm trying to avoid is having to translate the query into the PHP "native driver"'s format... I don't want to hand build arrays and hand-chain functions any more than I want to manually build an array of MySQL's internal query structure just to get data.

I already have a string producing the exact content I want in the Mongo console:

```
db.intake.find({"processed": {"$exists": "false"}}).sort({"insert_date": "1"}).limit(10);
```

The question is, is there a way for me to hand this string, as is, to MongoDB and have it return a cursor with the dataset I request?

Right now I'm at the "write your own parser because it's not valid json to kinda turn a subset of valid Mongo queries into the format the PHP native driver wants" state, which isn't very fun.

I don't want an ORM or a massive wrapper library;  I just want to give a function my query string as it exists in the console and get an Iterator back that I can work with.  I know there are a couple of PHP-based Mongo manager applications that apparently take console-style queries and handle them, but initial browsing through their code, I'm not sure how they handle the translation.

I absolutely love working with mongo in the console, but I'm rapidly starting to loathe the thought of converting every query into the format the native writer wants...

Comment: fyi; this is going to be much slower..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> I don't want to hand build arrays and hand-chain functions...

Your shell code is filled with *"hand build dictionaries"* and *"hand-chain functions"*. All of those dots are chained functions and all of the JSON represent dictionaries / hash tables.

Let's do a quick comparison.

**Javascript:**

```
db.intake
  .find({"processed": {"$exists": false}})
  .sort({"insert_date": "1"})
  .limit(10);
```

**PHP:**

```
db->intake
  ->find(array('processed'=> array('$exists'=> false)))
  ->sort(array('insert_date'=> '1'))
  ->limit(10);
```

So I basically replaced

- "dots" with "arrows"
- "colon" with "double arrow"
- "left brace" with "array("
- "right brace" with ")"

It sounds like you're really angry at PHP. And I can understand that PHP can be an obtuse language. However, when it comes to the MongoDB PHP driver, the syntax is as close as humanly possible to the "original" javascript.

Comment: I like your 'conversion rule'. Useful for testing queries at the shell and moving them to a PHP script when they are polished.

Comment: it's better not to use double quotes in queries. "$exists", "$not", "$nin" etc. since php tries to attempt evaluate it as a variable in first place. it's better to write with single quotes.

Comment: But why can't you use array literals when querying Mongo? Seems a bit weird.

Comment: if you are using older version of php/Mongo then use can use $mongo->execute() query. It's very useful

Answer (score 2):

You could use `json_decode()` to still do the query efficiently (using `MongoDB::execute` isn't as efficient) and get a cursor back. E.g.,

```
$db->intake->find(json_decode('{"processed": {"$exists": "false"}}'))
    ->sort(json_decode('{"insert_date": "1"}'))->limit(10);
```

Not sure if that is any better to you than using associative arrays, but it's an option. That way you only have to look at "JSON" query syntax.

(Also, I think you mean `$exists:false`, not `$exists:"false"`.)

Answer (score 0):

[MongoDB::execute](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.execute.php) is supposed to let you run any JavaScript code, but will return strings unfortunately, so you'd need to actually iterate the dataset using only JavaScript.

```
>> $d = new Mongo
Mongo::__set_state(array(
   'connected' => true,
   'status' => NULL,
   'server' => '',
   'persistent' => NULL,
))
>> $db = $d->database;
MongoDB::__set_state(array(
   'w' => 1,
   'wtimeout' => 10000,
))
>> $db->execute('db.intake.find({"processed": {"$exists": "false"}}).sort({"insert_date": "1"}).limit(10);');
array (
  'retval' =>
  array (
    'value' => 'DBQuery: database.intake -> undefined',
  ),
  'ok' => 1,
)
```