# Pass mongo shell query to mongo-php-library as string

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-.net-driver, php-mongodb

Below is the query i want to run using mongo-php-library,
I want to pass the query as string to the driver. Don't want to convert the json into php arrays.

```
db.getCollection('_survey.response').aggregate([
    {
        $match:
        {
            $and:[
                {
                    "Provider.Name": {
                    $in:[
                            "Comcast",
                            "AT&T"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    CreatedOn: {
                        $lt: ISODate('2017-05-10'),
                        $gt: ISODate('2017-01-01')
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        $group:{
            _id: {
                Status : "$Status",
                Survey: "$SurveyName"
            },
            SurveyId: {$addToSet: "$SurveyId"},
            Count: {$sum: 1}
        }
    },
    {
        $group:{
            _id: {
                SurveyName: "$_id.Survey"
            },
            Status: {$push: "$_id.Status"},
            Count : { $push : "$Count" } 
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            _id: 0,
            SurveyId: "$_id.SurveyId",
            Survey: "$_id.SurveyName",
            Status: 1,
            Count: 1
        }
    }
]);
```

This is the library i am using, [mongo-php](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library)

I have already seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8300046/how-do-i-do-mongodb-console-style-queries-in-php).

I have done the similar thing using mongo c# driver. Below is the c# code,

```
static void TestMongoShellV3()
{
    var start = new DateTime(2017, 01, 01, 9, 57, 44);
    var end = new DateTime(2017, 12, 01, 18, 5, 18);
    string dbname = "SURVEY_POC_MOIZ";
    string collname = "_survey.response";
    _database = _client.GetDatabase(dbname);
    var collection = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(collname);
    string bson = @"[
        {
            $group:{
                _id: {
                    Status : '$Status',
                    Survey: '$SurveyName',
                    SurveyId: '$SurveyId'
                },
                Count: {$sum: 1}
            }
        },
        {
            $group:{
                _id: {
                    SurveyName: '$_id.Survey',
                    SurveyId: '$_id.SurveyId',
                },
                Status: {$push: '$_id.Status'},
                Count : { $push : '$Count' } 
            }
        },
        {
            $project:{
                _id: 0,
                SurveyId: '$_id.SurveyId',
                Survey: '$_id.SurveyName',
                Status: 1,
                Count: 1
            }
        },
        {
            $sort: {Survey: -1}
        }
    ];";
    var pipeline = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonArray>(bson).Select(p => p.AsBsonDocument).ToList<BsonDocument>();
    var result = collection.Aggregate<BsonDocument>(pipeline).ToList();
    showResult(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with the [new driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library), as it does not have the [execute](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.execute.php) method anymore. Here is an extras from the docs:

> Warning
>
> The » eval command, which this method invokes, is deprecated in MongoDB 3.0+.

Regarding this:

> Don't want to convert the json into php arrays.

This is the only solution. You could use `json_decode` to programmatically convert the `string` to `array` before executing the query.